# OverlayItem hold more than title + snippet

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm looking for a way to make Overlayitem hold more than just a title and snippet, e.g a link to a picture, a music file playing.. something like that. is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `OverlayItem` and hold onto whatever you like.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how exactly I'd do this, do you have any links or perhaps an example?

Comment: @Meowmix: I don't have a simple example. Here is a complex one: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/ILuvNooYawk/  However, it is pretty much just standard Java (e.g., `class CustomItem extends OverlayItem`).